# Deleting files doesn't free up space

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I have a secondary hard drive I am using just for data and I'm trying to free up space on it but I'm finding deleting files only frees up a fraction of the expected space. For example, I deleted 20 GB worth of files, and gained 10 GB worth of space. Sometimes the ratio is much worse than that. It's like the files aren't being removed properly. How do I get the files to be deleted so that they are actually removed in full and I regain the space they were using? All hidden files are shown, and they're not showing up as still there. It also doesn't have a recycle bin or similar on that drive.

Comment: Do you have NTFS compression on? Some file names would be in blue if so.

Comment: @Tetsujin Doesn't look like it.

Comment: I have managed to free up a bit of space using the Disk Cleanup tool that comes with Windows 7, but there's still a bit unaccounted for. A lot better than it was though.